# How to picture "for" loop in block representation of algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have probem / strange question, i got algorithm with few "for" loops and now i need to do block scheme of this algorithm.

I know how to picture "while" loop, but is this acceptable to represent "for" loop using "while" and at this point make difference between souce code and algorithm?. Ofcourse assuming that all "for" loops are right in place and using loop of any other kind would produce unnecessary code which i avoided using "for" loops.

I'm guessing that this is rather impossible (at least I can't imagine this) to simply picture "for" loop, but maybe there is a way (if exists).

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is a for loop besides a while loop?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's a flow chart that illustrates a for loop:

[image: Flow Chart For Loop]

The equivalent C code would be

```
for(i = 2; i <= 6; i = i + 2) {
    printf("%d\t", i + 1);
}
```

I found this and several other examples on one of [Tenouk's C Laboratory practice worksheets](http://www.tenouk.com/clabworksheet/labworksheet7_1.html).

Comment: It is so obvious, i didn't realized it till i saw solution, probably it would came by itself when i would start to picturing my algorithm, THANKS

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Sometimes it's just reassuring to see that others are thinking along the same lines.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The image and link are both broken. Do you have a copy of this reference perchance?

Comment: @Sundeep No, but I did find a good replacement (and the image is now hosted on stack.imgur.com, so it won't disappear again).  Thanks for the alert.

Answer (score 3):

What's a "block scheme"?

If I were drawing it, I might draw a box with "for each *x* in *y*" written in it.

If you're drawing a flowchart, there's always a loop with a decision box.

Nassi-Schneiderman diagrams have a [loop construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Test_First.jpg) you could use.

Comment: Sorry my english isn't so great, but i hpoe you got idea what i mean

Answer (score 0):

**The Algorithm for given flow chart :**

[image]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

***Step :01***

- Start

***Step :02***
      [Variable initialization]

- Set counter:  ***i<----K*** [Where **K**:Positive Number]

***Step :03***[Condition Check]

- If condition True then Do your task, set **i=i+N** and go to Step :03 [Where **N**:Positive Number]
- If condition False then go to Step :04

***Step:04***

- Stop