# Showing nested for loops in a flowchart

Tags: loops, flowchart

How could I show a nested loop in a flowchart?

I want to show a nested foreach loop in a flowchart that shows something like this

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    foreach($SecondArray as $key=>$value) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no way to show a foreach loop in a flowchart, so I'd need to show a for loop in the diagram(?) So the algorithm should be shown as something more like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arrayTwo); $j++) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Now looking at the answers to this question ([How to picture “for” loop in block representation of algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879250/how-to-picture-for-loop-in-block-representation-of-algorithm)), a single for loop could be shown like this:

[image: Flowchart for single loop]

But I cannot think of any way in which I could show a nested loop (to show the code I wrote above).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

[image]

You can see other interesting flowchart for nested loops [here](https://www.programtopia.net/c-programming/docs/nested-loop).

Comment: Thank you. That was so obvious it kinda hurts haha. May I just asked if you used LaTeX to create that diagram by any chance?

Comment: I actually took it from the link mentioned at the bottom in the answer. To draw the easy flowcharts I have used https://www.draw.io/ till now.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that there haha. Well thanks for your help! :)