# For loop with object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I come across this code below which add a specified property value of all block of a nested object to an **array called arrays**.
My problem is that  I don' t understand how iteration works in a nested object like the one below using **for loop**.

*Can someone explain to me how for loop iteration is possible with an object?*

```
let list = {
   value: 1,
   rest: {
      value: 2,
      rest: {
         value: 3,
         rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

**below is the function that  does the job**

```
function listToArray(list) {
  let arrays = [];
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) { // big question: how it works or possible?
    arrays.push(node.value);
  }
  return arrays;
}
console.log(listToArray(list)); // -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Each iteration it reads the rest property, when it gets to the last one, it is undefined so stops

Comment: It does not "iterate" over general object properties, it just accesses "rest" and "value" properties of an object with a **specific** structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How do `for` loops work:**

First you need to understand how [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loops works.

> The for statement creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement (usually a block statement) to be executed in the loop. <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)</sup>

The `for` loop has this structure:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

The expressions `initialization`, `condition` and `final-expression` could be any valid expression. Any or all of these expressions could be omitted (`for(;;)` is valid in javascript and it creates an infinite loop).

The `for` loop begins by executing the `initialization` expression if specified, then repeats the following actions: check if the `condition` is truthy, if so then it executes `statement`(s) and `final-expression` in order, if the `condition` is falsy it stops looping.

Here is an example, the following diagram <sup>([image source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879273/9867451))</sup>:

[image: for loop diagram]

Corresponds to the follwing `for` loop:

```
for(i = 2; i <= 6; i = i + 2)
  print i + 1
```

Notice that the `initialization` part `i = 2` is only executed once whereas the rest (the `condition` part `i <= 6`, the `statement`(s) part and the `final-expression` `i = i + 2`) could be executed multiple times (in order) depending on the `condition`.

**Explanation of the code in question:**

```
for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) { // big question: how it works or possible?
  arrays.push(node.value);
}
```

The `initialization` part of this loop just declares the variable `node` and sets its value to the root element `list`, this part is only executed once, when the loop is about to start.

The `condition` part checks whether `node` (the variable) is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or not, in javascript an object is truthy whereas `undefined` is not, it's a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value (there are other truthy and falsy values of course but we are only interested in these two for this particular example). The concept of the loop is running down the object from node to node (see the `final-expression` part bellow). When a child node exists, the next value of `node` will be that node (which is an object), that means it's gonna be a truthy value, hence the condition will be true. Whereas if the child node doesn't exists, `node` will be `undefined` (a falsy value) and thus the condition will be falsy.

The `final-expression` just sets the value of `node` to the child node of the current node which is `node.rest`. If it exists `node` will be an object, otherwise it will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks you got the best answers

Answer (score 1):

As an introduction, first note the for loop has the following syntax:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    // code block to be executed
}
```

> 1. **`Statement 1`** is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.
> 2. **`Statement 2`** defines the condition for executing the code block.
> 3. **`Statement 3`** is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

So, on every iteration you are going one level deep of the `tree` with `node = node.rest`. The loop stops because eventually you will try to access property `rest` on some `node` that don't have that **key** or is set to `null`, this will be evaluated to `undefined` or `null` respectively, and since the stop condition of the `for` loop is to test the variable `node` it will stop when this is `undefined` or `null` (Note these are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values on Javascript).

**Example with debug**:

```js
let list = {
   value: 1,
   rest: {
      value: 2,
      rest: {
         value: 3,
         rest: null
    }
  }
};

function listToArray(list)
{
    let arrays = [];
    
    for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest)
    {
        console.log("Current node is: " + JSON.stringify(node));
        console.log("Node value is: " + node.value);
        arrays.push(node.value);
        console.log("Next node will be: " + JSON.stringify(node.rest));
    }

    return arrays;
}

console.log(listToArray(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop consists of three parts

1. initialization - will be called once (`let node=list`)
2. condition to continue - will be called on each iteration (`node`)
3. next step - will be called when a **2** returned `true`. Usually you want to update a variable created in the **1**

Let's have a closer look at what is actually happening here:

```
for(let node = list; node; node=node.rest)
```

First, you are creating a new variable called `node` with the value of `list` 
Next, you are checking if your isn't currently `null` or `undefined`. Theese two values are falsy, which means they both returns `false` when they are coerced to a boolean. If it's not, your `arrays.push` will be executed, otherwise your loop will be terminated. 
Last, you are updating your `node` with a value of the `node.rest`. Before your `arrays.push` will be executed with the updated `node`, your condition will be checked again. 
Finally, when your `node` is

```
{
   value: 3,
   rest: null
}
```

your **3** part of the loop will update the `node` variable assigning `rest` to it, which is `null` and your **2** won't pass, so it'll be terminated

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to access the nested object containing `value: 3`. Then you'd do:

```
 list.rest.rest // { value: 3, rest: null }
```

You could also write that into multiple lines as:

```
 let node = list; // { value: 1, rest: { ... } }
 node = node.rest; // { value: 2, rest: { ... } }
 node = node.rest; // { value: 3, rest: null }
```

and that can be generalized for n repetitions as

```
 for(let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
   //...
 }
```

---

Real world example:

You are living in a small village, there is only one street from north to south. There are a few houses next to the street. You are living at the end of the small town, at the northern end. Your neighbour's name is Bob. Bob also got a neighbour called Alice. Alice got a neighbour called Eve. Now if you want to walk along the street , you could either visit Bob, then Alice, then Eve. Or you just walk to the next house until you reached te end of the little town.

```
 const bob = you.southernNeighbour;
 const alice = bob.southernNeighbour;
 const eve = alice.southernNeighbour;

 // ...

let current = you; // you start where you are.
while(current) // as long as there is a house, walk 
  current = current.southernNeighbour; // go to the next southern neighbour
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make this recursive, as this makes it easier to explain.

If your object is `null`, just return the array (as it stands), else return a call to the next `rest` and add the `value` to the array.

```
obj = { value: 1, rest: {...} }, arr = []          // Add 1 to arr and return obj.rest
obj = { value: 2, rest: {...} }, arr = [ 1 ]       // Add 2 to arr and return obj.rest
obj = { value: 3, rest: null  }, arr = [ 1, 2 ]    // Add 3 to arr and return null
obj = null,                      arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ] // Return arr [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

```js
let list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};

function listToArray(obj, arr = []) {
  return obj == null ? arr : listToArray(obj.rest, arr.concat(obj.value));
}

console.log(listToArray(list)); // -> [1, 2, 3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` can be viewed as a syntactical sugar for `while`, even if there are a few low-level differences, these are the same:

```js
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

let i=0;
while(i<10) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

The syntax of `for` is `for(initialization, test, iteration)`. This:

```
for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) { doSomething(node); }
```

Is perhaps easier to understand if written as this:

```
let node = list;
while(node) { // equivalent to: while(node!==null) {
  doSomething(node);
  node = node.rest;
}
```